# Change "this" scope for backbone collection.create

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I do this in a dirty way, wondering if there's a nicer way:

```
this.collection.create(
    {
        'name': this.$('.name').val()
    },
    {
        success: function() {
            alert(_this);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert(_this);
        },
        wait: true
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you've set `var _this = this;` somewhere but just forgot to include it.

What you can do is to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) (EcmaScript 5) to bind the success and error callbacks to the right context.

```
success: function() {
    alert(this);
}.bind(this),

error: function() {
    alert(this);
}.bind(this),
```

That's supported in IE9 and up.

(If for some reason you're supporting IE8 there's a polyfill on the MDN page)

Answer (score 1):

With latest backbonejs you could pass context via options by using `context` keyword and don't use any polyfills at all :

```
this.collection.create(
    {
        'name': this.$('.name').val()
    },
    {
        success: function() {
            alert(this);
        },
        error: function() {
            alert(this);
        },
        context: this,
        wait: true
    }
);
```